# How loud is a 0.25W speaker supposed to be?

Tags: operational-amplifier, speakers, lm386

I know this is a very broad question; I just want to know what I should be expecting from it. At the moment it's hooked up to an LM386-N3 op-amp outputting a 5V single rail square wave and it is *whisper* quiet. I get distortion if I turn the input pot too far and I've tried it with 20 gain and 200 gain so I don't think it's the input signal. If I stand at the other end of my room I can't hear it at all. It's a basic 5cm diameter 8Ω paper cone hobby speaker.

Comment: Did you connect the speaker through a capacitor?

Comment: The input signal is connected through a 100nF ceramic cap and the output to the speaker is connected through a 220uF electrolytic cap.

Comment: What frequency are you trying to amplify?

Comment: It's a 976.5625hz square wave.

Comment: Speakers cannot develop normal volume (SPL) without being in some type of enclosure. If you speaker is not in some type of box or other enclosure, you should mount it in one for your testing.

Comment: I eventually discovered that I had a ceramic cap on the output connected in series instead of parallel. Oops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of a small transistor radio, they usually have a 5cm speaker and on full volume around 0.25W. That will easily be audible across a room.

You need to measure the voltage waveform across the speaker and work out the actual power, but it sounds like its a lot less than 0.25W.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but how do I do that? (I have an oscilloscope and a multimeter at hand)

Comment: Use the oscilloscope to measure the peak voltage of the output waveform, from there you can calculate the RMS power.

Comment: You can probably get quite close with just the multimeter.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can get much better than what you are achieving. You say that if you rise the volume the sound becomes acceptable but is distorted...

Let's take a step back. You are feeding your speaker with a square wave. That is pretty much the definition of distorted signal. If you want to have a more clean, less distorted signal on the output you should add a low pass filter somewhere in your signal path.

Not knowing what your circuit does or is supposed to do, nor knowing the schematic, I'm just gonna guess that you only will feed that 1kHz square wave to it. I am also assuming that the input signal is stiff enough to drive a passive, simple, first order low pass filter.

After your 100nF input cap add a series resistor, between the cap and the amplifier input, and hook a capacitor between the amplifier input and ground. Nice values for the components should be 8.2nF and 3.9kohm. You will obtain a first order lowpass filter with a cutoff frequency of about 5kHz, that should do the trick in cleaning your signal.